# react-native-chart-kit make standalone app crash when render

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-chart-kit

Im developing the react native app using expo cli, i have a screen with lineChart from react-native-chart-kit. My app working fine in expo go app but when im build the app using eas build to make it standalone when i open the screen with chart the app is crashing, ano solution to that?

I try to install react-native-build I tried adding this -keep public class com.horcrux.svg.** { *; } but nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Try to install react-native-svg library `npm install react-native-svg`. It worked for me.